# setinterval seems to accelerate

Tags: javascript

I have a setinterval within a function, on the first click all seems fine, but every subsequent click accelerates this timer. I don't understand why.

```
function startGame() {
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},100);
}
```

Comment: Do you need setTimeout instead of setInterval?

Comment: I want to call myTimer every tenth of second not once

Comment: Where does the click action come into this? Is the function `startGame()` started via a click?

Comment: You are probably setting the timer multiple times, so you have multiple timers firing, giving the appearance of acceleration.

Comment: If it's a game animation (canvas?) then you're far better off using requestAnimationFrame for all rendering: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When clicking second time, first interval also works, because of this event happens twice in 100ms. Try this:

```
var myVar;
function startGame() {
    if(myVar)
        clearInterval(myVar);
    myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},100);
}
```

OR:

```
var myVar;
function startGame() {
    if(!myVar)
        myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},100);
}
```

Comment: but I want this to update every tenth of second not once, startGame resets the myTimer

Comment: @DirkNachbar first example resets your timer

Answer (score 0):

Setinterval sets the function to run every X milliseconds, in your case I'd guess that you click once, and it starts to run every 100 ms, and then you click again and it starts a second one running every 100 ms (so now, on average you have one running every 50 ms).

I would recommend setTimeout, but I dont think thats what you need either. I think youre trying to use setinterval as a game loop, correct? In that case, you need a way to run it only once.